# How to use a specific version of aws-sdk in lambda function building by serverless and webpack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, webpack, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, serverless-framework

I need to use a higher version of aws-sdk than what lambda function provides by default. I am using serverless framework and webpack to build my serverless application. In serverless I can include or exclude dependencies in serverless.yml configuration:

```
package:
 individually: true
 include:
   - node_modules/aws-sdk
```

So I can provide my own aws-sdk in the package. But in my webpack config I have this configuration:

```
externals: [
   /aws-sdk/
],
```

which relies on aws-sdk on lambda container. When I remove this to not use the aws-sdk provided by lambda, I'm getting `JavaScript heap out of memory` error. What is the best way to accomplish this task?

```
    FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation 
    failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
    1: 0x10003b125 node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
    2: 0x10003b32f node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) 
    [/usr/local/bin/node]
    3: 0x1001a8e85 
    v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char 
    const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
    4: 0x1005742a2 v8::internal::Heap::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char 
    const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
    5: 0x100576d75 
    v8::internal::Heap::CheckIneffectiveMarkCompact(unsigned long, double) 
    [/usr/local/bin/node]
    6: 0x100572c1f 
 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollect 
 .or, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 7: 0x100570df4 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 8: 0x10057d68c v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithLigthRetry(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 9: 0x10057d70f v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
10: 0x10054f594 v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/usr/local/bin/node]
11: 0x100681149 v8::internal::String::SlowFlatten(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::ConsString>, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/usr/local/bin/node]
12: 0x1001c6c1d v8::String::Utf8Length() const [/usr/local/bin/node]
13: 0x10004eaac node::Buffer::(anonymous namespace)::ByteLengthUtf8(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
14: 0x10023170f v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(v8::internal::CallHandlerInfo*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
15: 0x100230c51 v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Object> v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::HandleApiCallHelper<false>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FunctionTemplateInfo>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::BuiltinArguments) [/usr/local/bin/node]
16: 0x1002302f0 v8::internal::Builtin_Impl_HandleApiCall(v8::internal::BuiltinArguments, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
17: 0xddb29a5be3d 
18: 0xddb29a118d5 
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: At what point are you getting the out of memory error?

Comment: @bwest I've added the stack trace.